# AutoHotkey - How to map a combination with AltGr to send a combination Ctrl+key to a specific Application?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to do the following:
Send to MusicBee the combination Ctrl+N (Next Track) whatever the application is currently active, by using AltGr+N key.

I've tried the following:

```
<^>!N::
if WinExist("ahk_exe MusicBee.exe")
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^n ; Send the keys to the last found window (found by WinExist)
```

which is supposed to work. The idea is to be able to circle through next tracks by keeping AltGr pressed, and pressing N multiple times. Means that I don't want to have to release AltGr key for the instruction to be sent to MusicBee.

Issue is the following:
When keeping AltGr pressed, the first time I press N, nothing will happen (I go through the shortcut (if I add a MfgBox, I see that I go through the code, but nothing happens. When I press N a second time, it will work. When I say nothing happens at the first time, this is not exact : this will lock my Left Control key to down state.
So if I'm for example in Notepad, I press AltGr+N (nothing happens in MusicBee), but then if I press just "O", the panel to open a file is displayed (as if Ctrl+O was pressed).

Then I've also tried:

```
ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^n{LCtrl up}
```

or

```
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {LCtrl down}n{LCtrl up}
```

but without success.

I've also played a bit with:

```
KeyWait N        ; wait the N key to be released
```

and

```
SetKeyDelay 10,10
```

but with no more success.

Do you have an idea how to avoid that the first combination to get AltGr will result in blocking LCtrl down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of AutoHotkey are you using? According to the developer -
see last post in this thread on the AutoHotkey forum here
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=6006 - "Several bugs relating to AltGr have been fixed ..."[1]

So if you are not using v1.1.33.02 try updating to the latest one - which is currently v1.1.33.02 - https://www.autohotkey.com/download/ - or you can use the "installer" script in your AutoHotkey folder to update as well - it might solve your problem.

[1] Look for AltGr on this https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AHKL_ChangeLog.htm page for an overview.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the right explanation. My version of AutoHotkey was 1.1.30. Updating to 1.1.33.02 solves the problem with AltGr.

Using the pattern:
<^>!N::
if WinExist("ahk_exe MusicBee.exe")
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^n
Return
;
is now working fine, without the issue keeping the left Control active.